# 2D table format Python

Tags: python, 2d, tabular

I want to create a 2D table format from my data stored in a dictionary.

Example:

```
d = {'ID1':[('Experiment1', 40), (Experiment2, 59), (Experiment3, 65)],    
 'ID2':[('Experiment1', 68), (Experiment2, 21), (Experiment3, 39)],   
 'ID3':[('Experiment1', 57), (Experiment2, 15), (Experiment4, 99)]}
```

Should give the following table:

```
    Experiment1     Experiment2     Experiment3     Experiment4
```

ID1 ...40................................59...............................65................................''
ID2....68...............................21................................39................................''
ID3....57...............................15................................''..................................99

Where IDx are the row labels and Experimentx are the column names.
If a dataset don't have a value to the column name, then an empty string should be added as placeholder.

Can anybody help how to do this? Is there any ready format in python, which I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty implementation (fixing your typos in the question ...)

```
d = {'ID1':[('Experiment1', 40), ('Experiment2', 59), ('Experiment3', 65)],    
 'ID2':[('Experiment1', 68), ('Experiment2', 21), ('Experiment3', 39)],   
 'ID3':[('Experiment1', 57), ('Experiment2', 15), ('Experiment4', 99)]}

COLUMN_WIDTH = 20
STRING_WHEN_MISSING = '""'
PADDING_STRING = "."


#first determine what are the columns - from the first line
columns = ["id"] #there is always at least the id column
columns = columns + [colName for (colName, colValue) in d.items()[0][1]]

print "".join([ col.ljust(COLUMN_WIDTH) for col in columns])

#browse the lines, order by ID Ascending
for (rowId, rowValues) in sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x: x[0].lower()):
    #print rowId
    #print rowValues
    rowValuesDict = dict(rowValues) #make it a dict with access by key
    rowValuesDict["id"] = rowId
    #print rowValuesDict
    print "".join([ str(rowValuesDict.get(col, STRING_WHEN_MISSING)).ljust(COLUMN_WIDTH, PADDING_STRING) for col in columns])
```

This prints out :

```
id                  Experiment1         Experiment2         Experiment3         
ID1.................40..................59..................65..................
ID2.................68..................21..................39..................
ID3.................57..................15..................""..................
```

### Note :

The format of your orginal dictionary is a bit strange ... I would expect more something like this :

```
d = [('ID1',{'Experiment1': 40, 'Experiment2':59, 'Experiment3':65}),    
     ('ID2',{'Experiment1': 68, 'Experiment2':21, 'Experiment3':39})]
```

### Some Comments:

For this kind of things, you want to read about some Python string methods : [center(), ljust() and rjust()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ljust) that add characters before and/or after a string to force its total width.

Appart from that, the idea is mostly about looping through lists/dictionaries and extract value.

Note the use of dict method [get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) that allows to have a default value when no value exists for a given key.

Comment: Thanks for this nicely commented example and the get() hint. I didn't know that or rather overlook it. This was actually the main problem...

Comment: You're welcome :) Right now I see an issue, that if the first line does not contain a value for all the possible columns, then the column will not show up in the output. You might need to loop through all the rows a first time do find out all the possible columns ... or you could hardcode the list of columns if it is static